# SMD pin component tip?

Tags: connector, pins

I'm looking for something like a metal pin that could be assembled on a flex PCB. SMD or through hole. I want to use it to twist and then solder a thin (1e-4) copper wire to. What component am I looking for?

A quick n dirty example for visualization.
[image: dirty sketch]
[image: Illustration]

Comment: This will be a custom part you'll either need to find a company that can make it for you or talk to a machine shop

Comment: There are are plenty of metal pins that you might suit you if you look at digikey or talk to a rep there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find such PCB terminals here: https://www.digikey.ee/short/d11qt3pj

But I am not so sure that's a good idea because of how easily the stress while you wrap and solder a wire could damage a flex circuit.

Consider instead a wire crimp terminal which is then connected to the flex circuit. For example (my site):

- [Board-in wire terminals to PCB](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=board_in_to_pcb_wire_terminals): crimped to a wire, inserted in a thru hole on the flex circuit, soldered
- ["AMP-edge wire terminal](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=removable_board_in_wire_terminals&s=AMP-Edge): crimped to a wire, slipped into a slit on the edge of the flex circuit, no soldering required
- [Foil terminal](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=foil_terminals): crimped to a wire, flags folded down onto flex, piercing it and making contact with conductors

Or, consider an [SMD test loop](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=pcb_loops): surface mount it to the flex circuit, then pass a wire through it and solder it.

Comment: Yes, SMD test points is ofc what I'm looking for! Thanks!